# Read more doesnt work with query posts

Tags: theme-development, query-posts, read-more

The tite says it all.

If I comment out the `query_posts` it works, if I don't it doesn't.

```
<?php // retrieve one post with an ID of 1
query_posts('p=27'); 
global $more;
$more = 1;
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<!-- <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4> -->
<?php the_content('read more'); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: It is not good practice to use query_posts.  If you want to retrieve one post use get_post() or for multiple get_posts().  And finally if you require more complex query, use WP_Query.

Comment: OK, can you show me how to do what I want with that? I changed query_posts('p=27') to get_post(27) but it lists all the posts I have, not just the one I want.

Answer (score 1):

With `query_posts('p=27');`  you request only the post with the ID equal to 27. Does this post exists and have the more tag in the content?

Also note that (taken from [Wordpress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Retrieve_a_Particular_Post)):

> If you want to use the Read More functionality with this query, you
>   will need to set the global $more variable to 0.

And you are setting the global $more variable to 1.

Also be sure to use the more tag in template files intended to display multiple posts: category, archive or index and home (index and home supports more tag only if you have set your home page to show your latest blog entries in the wordpress settings).

Comment: Yep. That is the reason I am using it, because I want a specific post.

Comment: I tried setting it to 0 before, same result. I dont even have that in my code anymore.

Comment: I've been testing and it dosen't work for me either in index.php and home.php. It works perfectly in category and archive templates. So I've change to some of the defaults templates and it works perfectly also in index and home.php tempaltes. So your problem can be related, as mine, with your template.

Comment: thanks for the info. dumb ass wordpress. I'll never understand why it is the no. 1 CMS.

Comment: It is not Wordpress fault that your template or plugin breaks some feature. Test in a default template to check if is the fault of your template or not. I'm quite new to Wordpress and I can say that it is deservedly number one CMS. I'm really happy with the decissions of moving from my previous CMS.

Comment: Why have you downvote my answer? I've pointed you where your problem is!!!!!!

Comment: I can't downvote. My rep is 1. And yes, it is wordpress fault.

Comment: So, have you test in a default template??

Comment: Yea, your answer didn't show the text, just the title. I found a better solution where you choose the category id instead of post, and then it works. Basically same thing just change query_posts to choose from a specific category instead of post. Wordpress... all in all I thank you for trying to help (but I can't upvote either coz of my rep :)

Comment: Forget the votes. I really think you have a problem in your theme, or maybe some plugin. Your code (not mine) is working perfectly in any of the core Wordpress themes. I've tested a lot of times.